# Geographically change domain keeping URL same

Tags: php, redirect, geoip

i am using this script to redirect users according to their IP.
But the problem is it redirects to homepage or only to URL i specify in the script. how can i just change the domain keeping the URL same? for example site.com/whateverpage redirected to site.au/whateverpage.

```
<?php
// Next two lines are for Beyond Hosting
// Don't forget to change your-domain
require_once '/home/your-domain/php/Net/GeoIP.php';
$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance('/home/your-domain/php/Net/GeoIP.dat');

// Next two lines are for HostGator
require_once 'Net/GeoIP.php';
$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance('GeoIP.dat');

try {
  $country = $geoip->lookupCountryCode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

  switch((string)$country) {
    case 'AU':
      $url = "http://www.site.au";
      break;
    case 'CA':
      $url = "http://www.site.ca";
      break;
    default:
      $url = "http://site.com";
  }

  if (strpos("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]", $url) === false)
  {
      header('Location: '.$url);
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Handle exception
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to your redirection.

```
header("Location: $url/$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
```

Comment: header('Location: '.$url/$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);   Is that right?